# Case sensitive files on a case insensitive filesystem haunts a repository

Tags: windows, git, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

A problem has reared it's ugly head after I foolishly used Ubuntu bash on Windows while working with a git repo. Apparently that introduces windows to the concept of case sensitive files and folders. This was fine until some colleagues that don't have that also began working with it.

I renamed some files, from "OurAPI" to "OurApi" and fixing some other trivial name related syntaxes. I don't know why but git saw these as new files and not moved ones, and the previous files deleted. Which in turn caused issues for my colleagues and vice versa.

I turned off the case-sensitive option for that folder, made a new repo and pushed there. Everything looked fine until I had to revert some commits. Now I have 3 modified files, related to the issue above.

I removed my local repository and cloned it anew, got these warnings:

```
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'OurAPI/OurAPI.csproj'
  'OurApi/OurAPI.csproj'
  'OurAPI/Services/DataService.cs'
  'OurApi/Services/DataService.cs'
  'OurAPI/Settings/AppSettings.cs'
  'OurApi/Settings/AppSettings.cs'
```

I can't add those files, commit those files or move those files.

`git status` always show these three as modified: *(freshly cloned remember!)*

```
    modified:   OurAPI/OurAPI.csproj
    modified:   OurAPI/Services/DataService.cs
    modified:   OurAPI/Settings/AppSettings.cs
```

Can I manually somehow edit the local git repository and kindly point out that they are the same file? Or remove the old file? Because if I do  `git rm OurAPI/OurAPI.csproj` it of course marks that file as no longer being tracked but I want it tracked, just not that old case-sensitive ghost file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this open source tool that seemed to do the trick:

https://github.com/tawman/git-unite

Followed the instructions, built it in PS using `build.cm`  and then `cd src\Git.Unite\bin\Debug` and finally `.\Git.Unite.exe C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Projects\OurApi`

`git status` then gave me the renamed files:

```
 rename {OurApi => OurAPI}/Startup.cs (100%)
 rename {OurApi => OurAPI}/packages.config (100%)
 rename {OurApi => OurAPI}/web.Debug.config (100%)
 rename {OurApi => OurAPI}/web.Release.config (100%)
 rename {OurApi => OurAPI}/web.config (100%)
```

Fingers crossed this won't mess up my colleagues next pull!